# Using mod_lua how do I write in apache's error_log without using the request_rec object?

Tags: lua, apache2.4, mod-lua

I know I can log using `r:debug()`,`r:info()` etc in `error_log`.But there are places in my code where I don't want to pass around the request. Is there something like `mod_python's` `apache.log_error()` in `mod_lua` to achieve this?

Comment: Not in the current releases.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just write to stderr, and you'll end up in the main (base configuration) ErrorLog